# Excel file corrupt after writing

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using the 3.10 Version of POI. Problem I am running into is that I am creating a xls,xlsx file. All looks good when writing the file. It is about 2MB. When I open in excel it truncates the file to 4K and I only get my column headers all the data is gone. If I try to open as xlsx it says it is corrupt. Anyone else hit this problem.

Here is the code that writes the row of data.

```
public void writeRow(int irow, String[] rdata) {
    Row row;
    Cell cell;
    int cellnum = 0;
    int rownum = irow;

    System.out.println("writeRow():ROW -> " + irow);
    row = _wSheet.getRow(irow);

    if (row == null) {
        System.out.println("writeRow():Creating Row " + irow);
        row = _wSheet.createRow(rownum);
    }

    for (String rdata1 : rdata) {
        cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
        cell.setCellValue((String) rdata1);
    }
    write();
}

public void write() {
    try {
        _gWorkbook.write(_outF);
        _outF.flush();
    } catch (IOException wbe) {
        System.out.println("write(): Error writing workbook "+wbe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be writing the file out once per row, which isn't what you want to do. You should only write the workbook out at the very end, when you're done

So, to fix it, change your code so that you only call [Workbook.write(OutputStream)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream%29) at the very end of your code. Don't try to do it as you go, the file format doesn't work like that

Comment: Ok tried that and get a 17K file. But when I open in Excel only column headers and it truncates file to 4k. This after I did as suggested wrote once after all rows created. I am guessing what you are saying is write the book once, period. I did the write of the columns, writebook, then started rows. SO I now will go back and change. Not sure how this is going to work with 20MB of data.Thanks Rob

Comment: You *must* only write out at the very end of all your changes, the Excel file format doesn't work incrementally. For very large files, either use CSV instead (that streams), or use SXSSF (with the restrictions that imposes)

Comment: Thanks that took care of it. Same code that does regular xls Now the XSSF (xlsx) fails on save.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setSaveCDataLengthThreshold(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions - Using the 2.6 XMLBeans

Comment: Looks like you have a second copy of xmlbeans then. You'll need to find and remove the older jar that's somewhere on your classpath which is taking priority over the one you meant to use

Comment: Checked with running -verbose. Unless there is an XMLeans buried in a Oracle Jar or BEA I am not seeing any except the one that comes with POI. I will look some more. But thanks on the xls, I will use that for now.

Comment: Something like Oracle or BEA will almost certainly bundle an old copy, they're notorious for shipping with ancient versions of everything and the kitchen sink :(