# Excel xlsx file gets corrupted after reading and removing row for the 2nd time using Apache POI 3.17

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to read a row from xlsx file and then remove the row. 
When I run my code once , it is perfectly fine. POI can read the row and remove the row. I can open the file using Excel. So far so good.

When I re-run my code once again (second time), POI can read the row and remove the row, but when I open the file using excel I see

[image]

I followed all suggestions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024118/apache-poi-content-in-excel-file-gets-corrupted) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318638/excel-file-corrupt-after-writing) , and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148355/file-is-corrupted-after-creating-excel-xlsx-file-by-using-apache-poi-with-jav) , but my problem still doesn't get solved.

This is my codes

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        new ExcelReader().readExcel(PATH_TO_EXCEL, Constants.sheetName);
        }

private void readExcel(String pathToExcel , String sheetName) throws InvalidFormatException {

        Sheet sheet = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToExcel));
            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fileInput);

            Iterator<Sheet> sheetItr = workbook.sheetIterator();
            while (sheetItr.hasNext()) {
                sheet = sheetItr.next();
                // For Users sheet create List of objects
                if (sheet.getSheetName().equals(sheetName)) {
                    readExcelSheet(sheet);
                } else {
                    // For other sheet just print the cell values
                    System.out.println("Sheet not available");
                }
            }

            //Now it's time to delete the row that we have just read
            removeAndShiftRow(PATH_TO_EXCEL,1,true, sheet);
            fileInput.close();

            FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(pathToExcel));
            workbook.write(outFile);
            outFile.flush();
            outFile.close();
            workbook.close();


        } catch (EncryptedDocumentException | IOException | ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


private void readExcelSheet(Sheet sheet) throws ParseException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Starting to read sheet- " + sheet.getSheetName());
        Iterator<Row> rowItr = sheet.iterator();
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        // Iterate each row in the sheet
        while (rowItr.hasNext()) {
            User user = new User();
            Row row = rowItr.next();
            // First row is header so skip it
            if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
                continue;
            } else if (row.getCell(1) == null || row.getCell(1).getCellTypeEnum().equals(CellType.BLANK)) {
                continue;
            } else if (formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0)).equals("USED")) {
                continue;
            } else {
                Iterator<Cell> cellItr = row.cellIterator();
                // Iterate each cell in a row
                while (cellItr.hasNext()) {

                    Cell cell = cellItr.next();
                    int index = cell.getColumnIndex();
                    switch (index) {
                        case 0:
                            System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            user.setIDNumber(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            //sheet.createRow(row.getRowNum()).createCell(0).setCellValue("USED");
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
                            user.setIDNumberShort(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            cell.setCellValue("used");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            user.setID(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            cell.setCellValue("used");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            user.setEmail(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            cell.setCellValue("used");
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            user.setFirstName(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            cell.setCellValue("used");
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            user.setLastName(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            cell.setCellValue("used");
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            user.setGender(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            cell.setCellValue("used");
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            user.setHomePhone(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            cell.setCellValue("used");
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            user.setMobile(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            cell.setCellValue("used");
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            user.setDOB(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            cell.setCellValue("used");
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            user.setAddress(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                            cell.setCellValue("used");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                userList.add(user);
                System.out.println("xxxxxxx");
                System.out.println(row.getRowNum());
                //removeRow(sheet, row.getRowNum());
                //this.deleteRow(row, sheet , WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_EXCEL)));
                break;
            }
        }
        for (User user : userList) {
            System.out.println(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName() + " " + user.getEmail() + " " + user.getDOB());
        }

    }


private static void removeAndShiftRow(String pathToExcel, int rowToBeRemoved, boolean removeIndexOneOnly, Sheet sheet) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        if (removeIndexOneOnly == true) {
            rowToBeRemoved = 1;

        }
        int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        Row row = sheet.getRow(rowToBeRemoved);
        if (row != null && rowToBeRemoved != lastRowNum) {
            //System.out.println(row.getCell(3).getRichStringCellValue()); //For Testing
            //System.out.println(row.getCell(4).getRichStringCellValue()); //For Testing
            System.out.println("row to be removed " + rowToBeRemoved);
            System.out.println("last row " + lastRowNum);

            sheet.removeRow(row);
            sheet.shiftRows(rowToBeRemoved + 1, lastRowNum, -1);
            //sheet.getWorkbook().setActiveSheet(sheet.getWorkbook().getSheetIndex(sheet));
        }

        if (rowToBeRemoved == lastRowNum) {
            System.out.println("Very Last Row");
            Row removingRow = sheet.getRow(rowToBeRemoved);
            if (removingRow != null) {
                sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
            }
        }
    }
```

`removeAndShiftRow()` method does not have any file I/O at all. 
All file I/O process is done in `readExcel()` method.

The xlsx file gets corrupted only when I run my codes for the 2nd time.   The 1st run will not make my file corrupted.

I am wondering where could be the issue.

Thanks.

**[Update]:**
I do some more investigation and I found a weird thing. 
The 1st run will just do perfectly fine. 
The 2nd run will change my second column from formula to string. Here is the snapshot.

[image]

[image]

Because of that change, the 3rd run will throw exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Master cell of a shared formula with sid=0 was not found
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.convertSharedFormula(XSSFCell.java:507)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getCellFormula(XSSFCell.java:491)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getCellFormula(XSSFCell.java:469)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter.formatCellValue(DataFormatter.java:984)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter.formatCellValue(DataFormatter.java:944)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter.formatCellValue(DataFormatter.java:923)
at Sandbox.ExcelReader.readExcelSheet(ExcelReader.java:110)
```

The exception points to method `readExcelSheet()` specifically this line

```
 case 1:
         System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
         user.setIDNumberShort(formatter.formatCellValue(cell)); //This will throw exception in the 3rd run
         cell.setCellValue("used");
         break;
```

Not sure which part is not done correctly.

Comment: are there any exceptions happening the second time you run your program? maybe the in/outputstreams dont get closed properly. have you already tried opening them via try-with-ressource?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem. But in my Machine it works - the file is not corrupted. You did not provide the implementation of the methods: removeAndShiftRow, readExcelSheet. Please provide your implementation, for further investigation.

Comment: Thanks ChristophE and Shahar.  No there is no exception thrown at all the 2nd time I run my codes. In fact, when I force Excel to repair it and open the file, the file looks like what I expected. Happy with the output. It is just corrupted.  I have attached my `removeAndShiftRow()` and `readExcelSheet()`.  These methods are just normal logic without any file I/O activities. Thanks :)

Comment: close the Excel File then run the program.

Comment: I always close the excel before running the codes. Otherwise, it would throw exception.

Comment: I added some more investigation results from today. Thanks :)

Comment: `Master cell of a shared formula with sid=0 was not found`: That means, in the originally sheet in `B2` was a formula `=RIGHT(A2,9)` used and filled downwards. There Excel's GUI has chosen using a shared formula instead of putting the same formula in all cells. A shared formula means, only `B2` contans the formula itself, `B3` contains the master formula having `<f ref="B3:B[n]" t="shared" si="0">RIGHT(A3,9)</f>` and `B4:B[n]` only contain references to that master formula by `si`. Now, if you delete `B3`, this master formula is gone.

Comment: So it seems `apache poi` does not handle such shared formulas properly while removing rows.

Comment: Thanks Axel. `B2` contains the original formula. `B3` contains master formula.  `B4 and the rests` only contain reference to `B3`. How come `B3` contains master formula? The way I did was I wrote the formula in `B2` , then copied and pasted it to `B3 and the rests`. So, shouldn't `B3 and the rests` contain reference to the original `B2` ?  I don't quite understand how excel works. Thanks.

Comment: "I don't quite understand how excel works.": Well, sometimes nobody understand `Microsoft`' s decisions ;-). But `*.xlsx` files are simple `ZIP` archives. So one can unzip them and have a look into. Do that and look at `/xl/worksheets/sheet[n].xml` then you will see.